# Why can't I match a substring which may appear 0 or 1 time using /(subpattern)?/

Tags: regex, perl

The original string is like this:

`checksession    ok:6178 avg:479 avgnet:480      MaxTime:18081   fail1:19`

The last part "**fail1:19**" may appear 0 or 1 time. And I tried to match the number after "**fail1:**", which is 19, using this:

```
($reg_suc, $reg_fail) = ($1, $2) if $line =~ /^checksession\s+ok:(\d+).*(fail1:(\d+))?/;
```

It doesn't work. The $2 variable is empty even if the "**fail1:19**" does exist. If I delete the "?", it can match only if the "**fail1:19**" part exists. The $2 variable will be "**fail1:19**". But if the "**fail1:19**" part doesn't exist, $1 and $2 neither match. This is incorrect.

How can I rewrite this pattern to capture the 2 number correctly? That means when the "**fail1:19**" part exist, two numbers will be recorded, and when it doesn't exit, only the number after "**ok:**" will be recorded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the number in `fail` field would end in `$3`, as those variables are filled according to opening parentheses. Second, as codaddict shows, the `.*` construct in RE is hungry, so it will eat even the `fail...` part. Third, you can avoid numbered variables like this:

```
my $line = "checksession ok:6178 avg:479 avgnet:480 MaxTime:18081 fail1:19";
if(my ($reg_suc, $reg_fail, $addend)
    = $line =~ /^checksession\s+ok:(\d+).*?(fail1:(\d+))?$/
) {
    warn "$reg_suc\n$reg_fail\n$addend\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes, it should be $3 to hold the number. Did the "?" after .* make it not hungry? Thanks for the advice to avoid using numbered variables.

Comment: @amazingjxq - yes, it is the way to make it non-hungry. It works also for `+`

Answer (score 2):

Try the regex:

```
^checksession\s+ok:(\d+).*?(fail1:(\d+))?$
```

[Ideone Link](http://www.ideone.com/xxJKK)

Changes made:

- `.*` in the middle has been made
  non-greedy and
- `$` (end anchor) has been added.

As a result of above changes `.*?` will try to consume as little as possible and the end anchor forces the regex to match till the end of the string, matching `fail1:number` *if* present.

Comment: That won't work as the `.*?` in the middle will match to the end of the string.

Comment: @Ben: It is `.*?` and not `.*` so it'll try to match as little as it can.

Comment: @ben This pattern works out. And the first one doesn't work. What is the use of "?" after **.*** in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one of the few cases where a split is actually more robust than a regex:

```
$bar[0]="checksession ok:6178 avg:479 avgnet:480 MaxTime:18081 fail1:19";
$bar[1]="checksession ok:6178 avg:479 avgnet:480 MaxTime:18081";
for $line (@bar){
    (@fields) = split/ /,$line;
    $reg_suc = $fields[1];
    $reg_fail = $fields[5];
    print "$reg_suc $reg_fail\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid the non-greedy modifier. It often bites back. Kudos for suggesting split, but I'd go a step further:

```
my %rec = split /\s+|:/, ( $line =~ /^checksession (.*)/ )[0];
print "$rec{ok} $rec{fail1}\n";
```

Comment: It should be `split ' |:'`. This is another way to do it.